Telerik Reporting - Negative Value Format Not working with .net 7
I have updated my project's version from .Net core 3.1 to .Net 7
and the Nuget package of Telerik reporting from version '17.2.23.1010' to '17.2.23.1114'.
I am using Telerik Report Designer to work with report files.
Some of my report's textboxes have a culture set as 'en-US' and format '{0:C2}' for currency format.
Before the version update, it was working fine to show negative values within parentheses '()'.
Now it does not show any parentheses for negative values.
There is not a single change made in the .trdp file.
Example values:
Before : ($322.25)
After  : -$322.25
So, any idea what is going on? Or any change I need to make according to the version update?
I tried resetting the culture and format on a textbox.
I am getting the expected output if I change the format from '{0:C2}' to '{0:$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00)}'.
However, I want to know the cause of why the old format is not working and the solution without changing the specific format on multiple files and boxes.
(manually updating files would be my last option if no other way)

According to the Telerik support team, this is a bug as well. And they have registered it to work on. For reference :
link

According to the Telerik forum team, this is a bug. They will look from their side in upcoming releases.
Checkout the response I received on the forum.
Telerik Forum
